# How to get the post content from a category on my homepage

Tags: get-posts, frontpage

I'm trying to get posts with a specific category to show in a box on my home page. But ive only been able to get one post on my homepage. How can I make this work in the code below?
With getting the title, excerpt (limit the characters - without read more) and post link (in the read more button below?)

```
echo '<section class="row"><div class="container-item">
            <div class="item">
            <div class="item-overlay">
            <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-top-content">
            <div class="item-top-content-inner">
            <div class="item-product">
            <div class="item-top-title">
            <h2>';
            echo get_the_title();
            echo '</h2><p class="subdescription">';
            the_excerpt();
            echo '</p></div></div></div>
            <div class="item-add-content">
            <div class="item-add-content-inner">
            <div class="section">
            <a href="#" class="btn buy expand">Read More</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>';
```

EDIT:

Thanks Pieter Goosen. This is the code with your suggestions and some minor edits which I ended up using with some jquery and css to create a pretty sliding box:

```
function homepage_highlights() { ?>
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=accommodation&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<section class="row"><div class="container-item">

       <div class="item" <body style="background-image:url(<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>)">
        <div class="item-overlay">
        <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-top-content">
        <div class="item-top-content-inner">
        <div class="item-product">
        <div class="item-top-title">
        <h3 class="title-front-page"><?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>'; ?>
        </h2></div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="item-add-content">
    <div class="item-add-content-inner">
    <div class="section">
    <p class="subdescription">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </p>

        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it. If my answer was usefull, please mark as such. You can also add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really necessary to echo so much. If you make proper use of opening and closing php tags you can eliminate using echo. And why are you echoing `get_the_title()` when there is a build in feature for that. `the_title()` does exactly the same.

You can use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create a special loop to get posts from a specific category. Just remember to reset your loop as you are going to start a new loop. For multiple loops, also check [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). One word of advice, the author of this page used `query_posts`, which you must not use at all, use `WP_Query`

As for the excerpt, you can change the read more link as follow

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <---the code of your button here--->';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

So in the end, your code should like like this

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=special_cat&posts_per_page=10'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<section class="row"><div class="container-item">
            <div class="item">
            <div class="item-overlay">
            <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-top-content">
            <div class="item-top-content-inner">
            <div class="item-product">
            <div class="item-top-title">
            <h2>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2><p class="subdescription">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p></div></div></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<---Start your new loop here --->
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter, you set me on the right track. I didn't realize I could avoid using echo by using <?php ?> tags properly.